# Unable to downlad file to load data on R

Tags: r

**OS**- Windows 7
**R** version 3.0.3
**What I typed on R console** :

```
if(!file.exists("data")){dir.create("data")}
fileUrl <- "https://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/dz54-2aru/rows.xlsx?accessType=DOWNLOAD"
download.file(fileUrl,destfile="./data/cameras.xlsx",method="curl")
dateDownloaded <- date()
```

**What I got on R console**

Warning messages:

```
1: running command 'curl  "https://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/dz54-2aru/rows.xlsx?accessType=DOWNLOAD"  -o "./data/cameras.xlsx"' had status 127 
2: In download.file(fileUrl, destfile = "./data/cameras.xlsx", method = "curl") :
```

download had nonzero exit status

**How do I make it right ?**

Comment: This is some 'interesting' formatting. Can you at least make the code formatted? FWIW, bold font doesn't make things more readable.

Comment: Try RCurl as in here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028760/download-csv-file-using-download-file-in-r

Comment: change the `https` to just `http` and skip `method="curl"` in the `download.file`. This doesn't always work but that file is available via plain 'ol `http`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me. You probably don't have cURL installed on your system. See `?download.file`:

> For methods "wget", "curl" and "lynx" a system call is made to the tool given by method, and the respective program must be installed on your system and be in the search path for executables.

Install [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) and make sure it is in your path.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the method="curl" parameter, it works well on Windows.