# Reading an online xlsx file into R

Tags: r

I am trying to download spreadsheets from AQR data library into R directly.
I have this link: http://www.aqr.com/~/media/files/data-sets/value-and-momentum-everywhere-portfolios-monthly.xlsx which prompts a download. However,  when trying the following code:

```
> url1<-"http://www.aqr.com/~/media/files/data-sets/value-and-momentum-everywhere-portfolios-monthly.xlsx"
> download.file(url1,destfile="example.xlsx")
```

I get this error

```
trying URL 'http://www.aqr.com/~/media/files/data-sets/value-and-momentum-everywhere-portfolios-monthly.xlsx'
Error in download.file(url1, destfile = "example.xlsx") : cannot open URL 'http://www.aqr.com/~/media/files/data-sets/value-and-momentum-everywhere-portfolios-monthly.xlsx'
```

https://www.aqr.com/library/data-sets/value-and-momentum-everywhere-portfolios-monthly is the page from which I am trying to download data(under full set data link).

Could you provide some guidance?

Comment: What's your R version? Your code worked for me.

Comment: I'm using [1] "R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)", could that be the problem?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Your version is even newer than mine. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that link redirects to https, which `download.file` does not support by default. If you have wget or curl installed you can use

```
download.file("https://www.aqr.com/~/media/files/data-sets/value-and-momentum-everywhere-portfolios-monthly.xlsx", 
              "example.xlsx", 
              method = "wget")
```

or

```
download.file("https://www.aqr.com/~/media/files/data-sets/value-and-momentum-everywhere-portfolios-monthly.xlsx", 
              "example.xlsx", 
              method = "curl")
```

These and other options are discussed at [Download a file from HTTPS using download.file()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028760/download-file-from-https-using-download-file-in-r)

Comment: Thanks, this finally worked for me.  Do you know why for some(like the other answer) they don't need to take this extra step?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what is causing the problem for you, but the following worked for me:

```
library(XLConnect)
## 
con <- "http://www.aqr.com/~/media/files/data-sets/value-and-momentum-everywhere-portfolios-monthly.xlsx"
download.file(con,"xlsxFile.xlsx",mode="wb")
##
newWB <- loadWorkbook(
  file="xlsxFile.xlsx",
  create=F)
##
R> getSheets(newWB)
[1] "VME Portfolios" "Definitions"    "Data Sources"   "Disclosures"
```

and here's a screenshot of the downloaded file:

[image]