# How do I use R to download LEHD data from the website?

Tags: r, rcurl, census

I would like to know how to download LEHD files from their FTP site.

https://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/lodes/LODES7/

I need to download the data for multiple years, for both workplace and resident place locations. The files are named regularly, and the technical documentation can be found here:

https://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/lodes/LODES7/LODESTechDoc7.2.pdf
S000 references all workforce segments
JT00 references all job types

So a typical file name is: ca_wac_S000_JT00_2008.csv.gz
In the 'directory'/URL of: https://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/lodes/LODES7/ca/wac/

[This bit of git-hub code seems relevant](https://github.com/Geschwindigkeitsbegrenzung/SGTG_LEHD/blob/master/0.%20downloading%20LEHD%20LODES%20data.R). The [Harvard tutorial](http://tutorials.iq.harvard.edu/R/RProgramming/Rprogramming.html) has been useful, and provided me with a way to create a list of all the files. But I can't get the actual download to work--[R.curl hasn't worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028760/download-a-file-from-https-using-download-file), as I run into the SSL issue.

The extended code doesn't seem to work either:

```
install.packages("RCurl")
library(RCurl)
options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))   
URL <- "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Fss06hid.csv"
x <- getURL(URL)
x
#the above code works.

#my implementation...fails
URL <- "https://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/lodes/LODES7/ca/wac/ca_wac_S000_JT00_2002.csv.gz"
x <- getURL(URL)
#results in following error:
#Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
# error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

> > devtools::session_info() Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  setting  value                         version  R version 3.4.3
> >     (2017-11-30)  system   x86_64, mingw32               ui       RStudio
> >     (1.1.383)             language (EN)                          collate 
> >     English_United States.1252    tz       America/Denver
> >     date     2017-12-17
>
> Packages
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  package    * version  date       source          acs        * 2.1.2
>   2017-10-10 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  assertthat   0.2.0    2017-04-11 CRAN (R
>   3.4.3)  base       * 3.4.3    2017-12-06 local           bindr        0.1      2016-11-13 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  bindrcpp     0.2      2017-06-17 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  class        7.3-14   2015-08-30 CRAN (R 3.4.3) 
>   classInt     0.1-24   2017-04-16 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  compiler     3.4.3
>   2017-12-06 local           curl       * 3.1      2017-12-12 CRAN (R
>   3.4.3)  datasets   * 3.4.3    2017-12-06 local           DBI          0.7      2017-06-18 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  devtools   * 1.13.4   2017-11-09 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  digest       0.6.13   2017-12-14 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  dplyr
>   * 0.7.4    2017-09-28 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  e1071        1.6-8    2017-02-02 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  foreign      0.8-69   2017-06-22 CRAN (R 3.4.3) 
>   gdtools    * 0.1.6    2017-09-01 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  git2r        0.19.0
>   2017-07-19 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  glue         1.2.0    2017-10-29 CRAN (R
>   3.4.3)  graphics   * 3.4.3    2017-12-06 local           grDevices  * 3.4.3    2017-12-06 local           grid         3.4.3    2017-12-06 local           hms          0.4.0    2017-11-23 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  httr 
>   1.3.1    2017-08-20 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  lattice      0.20-35  2017-03-25 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  lodes      * 0.1.0    2017-12-17 git (@8cca008) 
>   magrittr     1.5      2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  maptools     0.9-2
>   2017-03-25 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  memoise      1.1.0    2017-04-21 CRAN (R
>   3.4.3)  methods    * 3.4.3    2017-12-06 local           pkgconfig    2.0.1    2017-03-21 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  plyr         1.8.4    2016-06-08 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  purrr        0.2.4    2017-10-18 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  R6
>   2.2.2    2017-06-17 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  rappdirs     0.3.1    2016-03-28 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  Rcpp         0.12.14  2017-11-23 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  readr
>   1.1.1    2017-05-16 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  rgdal        1.2-16   2017-11-21 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  rgeos        0.3-26   2017-10-31 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  rlang
>   0.1.4    2017-11-05 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  sf           0.5-5    2017-10-31 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  sp         * 1.2-5    2017-06-29 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  stats
>   * 3.4.3    2017-12-06 local           stringi      1.1.6    2017-11-17 CRAN (R 3.4.2)  stringr    * 1.2.0    2017-02-18 CRAN (R 3.4.3) 
>   tibble       1.3.4    2017-08-22 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  tigris     * 0.5.3
>   2017-05-26 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  tools        3.4.3    2017-12-06 local
>   udunits2     0.13     2016-11-17 CRAN (R 3.4.1)  units        0.4-6
>   2017-08-27 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  utils      * 3.4.3    2017-12-06 local
>   uuid         0.1-2    2015-07-28 CRAN (R 3.4.1)  withr        2.1.0
>   2017-11-01 CRAN (R 3.4.3)  XML        * 3.98-1.9 2017-06-19 CRAN (R
>   3.4.1)

Answer (score 4):

If you can use GitHub-installable packages (it'll be a bit before I get this on CRAN) then you can give https://github.com/hrbrmstr/lodes a go:

```
devtools::install_git("https://github.com/hrbrmstr/lodes.git")

library(lodes)
library(dplyr)

de <- read_lodes("de", "od", "aux", "JT00", "2006", "~/Data/lodes")

glimpse(de)
## Observations: 68,284
## Variables: 13
## $ w_geocode  <dbl> 1.000104e+14, 1.000104e+14, 1.000104e+14, 1.000104e+14, 1.000104e+14, 1.000104e+14, 1.000104e+14...
## $ h_geocode  <chr> "240119550001006", "240119550001040", "240299501002080", "240299501003088", "240299503002017", "...
## $ S000       <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...
## $ SA01       <int> 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, ...
## $ SA02       <int> 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, ...
## $ SA03       <int> 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
## $ SE01       <int> 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, ...
## $ SE02       <int> 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, ...
## $ SE03       <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
## $ SI01       <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...
## $ SI02       <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
## $ SI03       <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
## $ createdate <int> 20160228, 20160228, 20160228, 20160228, 20160228, 20160228, 20160228, 20160228, 20160228, 201602...
```

It has a function to read & cache the crosswalk file and a function to read and cache the individual data files.

Please let me know if you still have the SSL failure and if so, please add the output of `devtools::session_info()` or `sessionInfo()` to your question.

Comment: library(devtools)
devtools::install_git("https://github.com/hrbrmstr/lodes.git")
library(lodes)
library(dplyr)
getwd()
setwd("N:/Dropbox/_BonesFirst/LODES")
de <- read_lodes("de", "od", "aux", "JT00", "2006", "N:/Dropbox/_BonesFirst/LODES")
glimpse(de)
#this works, as of 12/17/2017

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution [here](https://github.com/aakarner/job-growth-affordability/blob/master/00_Download%20and%20summarize%20LODES%20data.R). It's not perfect, as it loads the files into memory, rather than saving them to disk. But it does work for me.

```
years.to.download <- c(2002,2004,2014)
options(scipen = 999) # Supress scientific notation so we can see census geocodes
library(plyr); library(dplyr)
library(downloader) # downloads and then runs the source() function on scripts from github
library(R.utils) # load the R.utils package (counts the number of lines in a file quickly)


# Program start ----------------------------------------------------------------
tf <- tempfile(); td <- tempdir() # Create a temporary file and a temporary directory
# Load the download.cache and related functions
# to prevent re-downloading of files once they've been downloaded.
source_url(
  "https://raw.github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/master/Download%20Cache/download%20cache.R",
  prompt = FALSE,
  echo = FALSE
)
# Loop through and download each year specified by the user
for(year in years.to.download) {
  cat("now loading", year, "...", '\n\r')
#-----------Data import: residence area characteristics---------------------  
  # Data import: workplace area characteristics (i.e. job location data)
  # Download each year of data
  # Zipped file to the temporary file on your local disk
  # S000 references all workforce segments
  # JT00 references all job types
  download_cached(
    url = paste0("http://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/lodes/LODES7/ca/wac/ca_wac_S000_JT00_", year, ".csv.gz"),
    destfile = tf,
    mode = 'wb'
  )

# Create a variable to store the wac file for each year
  assign(paste0("wac.", year), read.table(gzfile(tf), header = TRUE, sep = ",",
                                          colClasses = "numeric", stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  # Remove the temporary file from the local disk
  file.remove(tf)
  # And free up RAM
  gc()

#-----------Data import: residence area characteristics---------------------
  download_cached(
    url = paste0("http://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/lodes/LODES7/ca/rac/ca_rac_S000_JT00_", year, ".csv.gz"),
    destfile = tf,
    mode = 'wb'
  )
    # Create a variable to store the rac file for each year
  assign(paste0("rac.", year), read.table(gzfile(tf), header = TRUE, sep = ",",
                                          colClasses = "numeric", stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
    # Remove the temporary file from the local disk
  file.remove(tf)
    # And free up RAM
  gc()
}
```