# How do I capture the HTTP error code from a download.file request?

Tags: r, http, curl, wget

This code attempts to download a page that does not exist:

```
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/asdfasdfasdf"
status_code <- download.file(url, destfile = "output.html", method = "libcurl")
```

This returns a 404 error:

```
trying URL 'https://en.wikipedia.org/asdfasdfasdf'
Error in download.file(url, destfile = "output.html", method = "libcurl") : 
  cannot open URL 'https://en.wikipedia.org/asdfasdfasdf'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile = "output.html", method = "libcurl") :
  cannot open URL 'https://en.wikipedia.org/asdfasdfasdf': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

but the `code` variable still contains a 0, even though the documentation for `download.file` states that the returned value is:

> An (invisible) integer code, 0 for success and non-zero for failure. For the "wget" and "curl" methods this is the status code returned by the external program. The "internal" method can return 1, but will in most cases throw an error.

The results are the same if I use `curl` or `wget` as the download method. What am I missing here? Is the only option to call `warnings()` and parse the output?

I've seen [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23028760/2766558) about using `download.file`, but none (that I can find) that actually retrieve the HTTP status code.

Comment: i don't know R, nor the download.file wrapper, but the underlying libcurl way of getting the code is `long response_code; curl_easy_getinfo(ch,CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE,&response_code);` - check if your download.file api expose libcurl's curl_easy_getinfo() somehow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the best option is to use cURL library directly rather than via the `download.file` wrapper which does not expose the full functionality of cURL. We can do this, for example, using the RCurl package (although other packages such as httr, or system calls can also achieve the same thing). Using cURL directly will allow you to access the cURL Info, including response code. For example:

```
library(RCurl)
curl = getCurlHandle()
x = getURL("https://en.wikipedia.org/asdfasdfasdf", curl = curl)
write(x, 'output.html')
getCurlInfo(curl)$response.code
# [1] 404
```

Although the first option above is much cleaner, if you really want to use `download.file` instead, one possible way would be to capture the warning using `withCallingHandlers`

```
try(withCallingHandlers( 
  download.file(url, destfile = "output.html", method = "libcurl"),
  warning = function(w) {
    my.warning <<- sub(".+HTTP status was ", "", w)
    }),
  silent = TRUE)

cat(my.warning)
'404 Not Found'
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind using a different method you can try `GET` from the `httr` package:

```r
url_200 <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)"
url_404 <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/asdfasdfasdf"

# OK
raw_200 <- httr::GET(url_200)
raw_200$status_code
#> [1] 200

# Not found
raw_404 <- httr::GET(url_404)
raw_404$status_code
#> [1] 404
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>