# download.file corrupts .mp3 file in R

Tags: r, audio, download, mp3

I'm trying to download a long list of podcasts, but when I use the download.file command in R it corrupts the audio file into a bunch of crackling noises.

Could any of you recommend a dedicated audio-downloading package, or recommend a download.file method that would be better suited for download audio. I went through the ones listed in the help file, but none worked. ("auto", "internal", "wininet", "libcurl", "wget" and "curl")

The downloading portion of the code looks similar to this:

```
url <- "http://play.podtrac.com/npr-510289/npr.mc.tritondigital.com/NPR_510289/media/anon.npr-mp3/npr/pmoney/2016/06/20160603_pmoney_podcast.mp3?
orgId=1&amp;d=1121&amp;p=510289&amp;story=480606726&amp;t=podcast&amp;e=480606726&amp;siteplayer=true&amp;dl=1"

download.file(url = url, destfile = "test.mp3")
```

I attempted different audio files from different sites and had similar results.

Edit: In response to the question by VC.One, this a [url](https://hexed.it#base64+lzjb:%202018-03-31%20StackOverflow%20Planet%20Money%20Question;IP/7kEAAcAFJbgRmbwAjBwAArToAARotGwACBQcADQoMDxEUFxkAHB4hIyYoKy4AMDM1ODo9QEIARUdKTE9RVFcAWVxeYWNmaGsAbnBzdXh6fYAAgoWHioyPkZQAl5mcnqGjpqgAq66ws7W4ur0AwMLFx8rMz9EA1NfZ3N7h4+YA6Ovu8PP1+Pq+/QBx/AP8QvxC9EL/FaIAS4AAAAgAAAkAcAAAAQD8CR4AhKQAIB+BI9AAlIAELAACQCYACYuwWAAEgEwAExdgftmtt1sAbbGQyw2SATEAEuOa7c39JSAAHtnwhB5PYsQAphYgs+lWmmQANwztd5XZmCIAM1tjwVkyZ60Ae308EW5a) to the initial section of the Hex code. I added in more than the couple of lines he requested because the first section looked like file information which may or may not be relevant:

Comment: Try an alternate library. Read this case for example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028760/download-a-file-from-https-using-download-file/23029305#23029305

Comment: I had looked at RCurl, but the way I understood it, it is more catered towards extracting text from a large number of sites. 

If you have suggestions for other packages, I would love to hear them.

Comment: Use a **Hex editor** (download it or just use an online hex viewer) and select maybe 8 lines worth of byte values then copy/paste into your question. This will make it easier for us to see how the data (bytes) are corrupted and suggest a fix.

Comment: Dear VC, thanks for the suggestion and my apologies to the late reply. I added in a section of the initial hex code of the file I downloaded using the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mode = "wb" in download.file(). I had the same issue you mentioned and this solved it for me.