# Download.file with method curl downloads 0 bytes

Tags: r, curl

When I use the `download.file` function with method `curl` I get a downloaded file with `0` bytes.

for example:

```
download.file('https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/archive/refs/heads/main.zip', destfile='library', method='curl')
```

Produces the following output:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
character(0)
```

How can I get this fixed?

Note:
`method='wget'` works but that is because my Mac has `wget`, however my windows laptop only has `curl` as an option, and this does not work. I specifically want to fix the curl method.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028760/download-a-file-from-https-using-download-file

Comment: @br00t I have seen this and it did not help. Everyone provided only alternatives to `method='curl'` rather than providing a solution with its use.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you running @Working dollar? As of Windows 10 `curl` is bundled with the OS so no need to install any binaries. Earlier version may require you to download a `curl` binary and put the binary into your `PATH` variable. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507353/how-do-i-install-and-use-curl-on-windows